# Java regex for numeric input with '-' char in the beginning is acceptable

Tags: java, regex

I need to support inputs of int numbers like "100", double like "150.84", but also be able to accept an input like this "-458.2" or "-450".

For the int/double part I use :
`input.matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")) || input.matches("\\d+"))`

But how can make it acceptable to have the minus character at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow an optional `-` like this:

```
 input.matches("-?\\d+\\.\\d+"))
```

You can also write it in one Regex:

```
input.matches("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
```

`?:` declares a non-capturing group since you don't want to extract this part